# Regex splitting on whitespace exept in quotes or square brackets

Tags: regex

So as the title says, I try to split a string by whitespace but not inside double quotes or square brackets

I have tried this but it gives me error: 
.match(/(?|[([^]]*)]|"([^"]*)"|(\w+))/g);

And to modify this which works with roundbrackets instead of square brackets, but without luck: 
/([^)]+?[)]|[""].+?[""]|[^ ]+/g

What I want:

example dummy string: 
sometext here " stuff here " [hello " otherstuff " 3] "goodbye" 
the response I want: 
[sometext, here, " stuff here ", [hello " otherstuff " 3], "goodbye"]

If anyone knows how to write the correct regex, I would be forever grateful

Comment: Which language/tool/framework are you using and what is the error you're receiving?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse a defined format, maybe Python's dump format?  If so, I would look for existing tools that already parse that format for you.

Comment: I'm using node/typescript. I will get back with the error in a second

Comment: No regex will help you if there can be nested brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this:

```js
  var str = `sometext here " stuff here " [hello " otherstuff " 3] "goodbye"`;
  var patt = /(\w+)|(\".+?\")|(\[.+?\])/g;
  var result = str.match(patt);
  console.log(result);
```

You either match on a word, stuff between quotes or stuff between square brackets!
Here's [your example using regexr](https://regexr.com/5qdo5).

[image]

Comment: Thannks for the suggestion, I will test in a sec

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @LukeGarrigan quick question, it now splits on comma(,) and dot(.). Is there any way the that regex can ignore comma or dot, or both of them?

Comment: @JørgenEriksen sure you could do `([\w.,]+)|(\".+?\")|(\[.+?\])` so it'll include the comma and dot in the capture

Answer (score 2):

Use

```js
string.match(/"[^"]*"|\[[^\][]*]|[^\s\][]+/g)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/VqAJMy/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\][]*                  any character except: '\]', '[' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ]                        ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\s\][]+                any character except: whitespace (\n, \r,
                           \t, \f, and " "), '\]', '[' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
```

**Code**:

```js
const string = `some.text here " stuff here " [hello " otherstuff " 3] "good-bye"`
console.log(string.match(/"[^"]*"|\[[^\][]*]|[^\s\][]+/g))
```